# Python, Load config file correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, config

I have the following directory:

- IoT [Folder]

  - DC [Folder]

    - main.py
    - config.ini

inside `main.py` I have:

```
config.read('config.ini')
```

which works perfect if I run my python script after doing `cd .....IoT/DC`

But it doesn't work once I run my python script directly from IoT folder, how can I solve this?

I can't know from which folder my program will be run...

If I have to choose one I prefer running it directly from IoT like this:

```
python3 DC/main.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import getcwd
from os.path import join

config_file_path = join(getcwd(), 'conf', 'config.ini')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Paths are relative to the current working directory, which is usually
> the directory from which you run your program (but the current
> directory can be changed by your program [or a module] and it is in
> general not the directory of your program file).

You can do something like this

```
import os
config.read(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'DC', 'config.ini'))
```

References :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__file__-a-special-variable-in-python/